# Event status bug: adding new values and modify it by widget (video inside)

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I need some help with Vtiger.

I noticed that changing the status of an event directly from the widget creates a bug on the event dates.
I would like to have an event history in every opportunity, each hesitated quickly via the widget, but this bug does not allow me to take advantage of this feature.

Could someone tell me how to avoid this date change?

I made a video to better explain the bug I'm talking about, thank you for any help.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jIzLcxzEiR8&feature=youtu.be

Comment: what vtiger version do you have? can you replicate the error on this instance: https://demo.vtiger.com/vtigercrm/ ?

Comment: I have 7.1, no the bug is not present in that demo

Comment: Well, you can upgrade to 7.2 then.

Comment: Yes you are right, i did it!

Comment: Be careful however, since there are other bugs in 7.2 as well. Like this one: https://code.vtiger.com/vtiger/vtigercrm/issues/1226 that prevents you from making profile changes. I advise you to keep an eye for a patch of 7.2 here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/vtigercrm/files/ and apply it ASAP.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I did it!